# Javascript: Prevent cursor hiding on keypress on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, user-interface, keyboard-events

I am developing a photo editor webapp [Photopea](http://httsp://www.Photopea.com).

When you press B, you switch to a Brush tool, that has a custom cursor. You can change the brush diameter with **[** and **]** keys (to make the diameter bigger or smaller).

When a key is pressed on MacOS, it hides the cursor, up until the mouse is moved. For users, who change the brush diameter with keys, the cursor disappears and they can not see the preview of the new diameter.

Native apps can prevent this default behaviour on Mac OS. Can web apps prevent it, too?

In the demo below, you can see, what happens to the cursor when you press keys:

```js
var down = [];
var msg = document.getElementById('state-msg');
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (down.indexOf(e.key.toLowerCase()) == -1) down.push(e.key.toLowerCase());
  msg.textContent = JSON.stringify(down);
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  down.splice(down.indexOf(e.key.toLowerCase()), 1);
  msg.textContent = JSON.stringify(down);
});
```

```html
<span id="state-msg"></span>
```

Comment: `Element.style.cursor = 'text'`

Comment: @PHPglue what do you mean? I need to keep showing a custom PNG cursor after any key is pressed.

Comment: That's not custom, it's the text cursor.

Comment: There's no OS feature to let you show the cursor when typing, same for  Chromebooks.

Comment: @RobG  It is not actually typing, but just using a keyboard shortcut for some different purpose. Native apps like Photoshop on Mac OS can do it (use a shortcut without hiding the cursor), so I thought this option is also exposed to web apps. Both developers and users would really appreciate it.

Comment: Pressing keys is typing. Native apps have access to the full system API, browsers only provide support for a very limited sub-set of a tiny fraction of that. You could write a native app to show the cursor, then link it to javascript, but that would require everyone using your script to install the app, see [*here*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71661/how-do-i-disable-hiding-of-the-mouse-pointer-while-typing-text).

Comment: You might be able to use the [*PointerEvent* interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) to [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) a [*pointermove* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointermove). You might be able to just move the cursor 1px in any direction then back again, or dispatching an event might make the pointer reappear even if it doesn't move.

Comment: @RobG Could you try to implement it in a JSFiddle above? (I don't have a Mac computer, but one of my users with Mac reported it).